# all the possible string the could be

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want a function in python that gets me all the possible string that start with 1 char to x of char like `'a','ab','ba','abc'`so on till it reach x of chars and try all the possible char that could be in this string

that's what i have tried:

```
from itertools import imap
     for string in imap(''.join,itertools.product('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890', repeat=62)):
         print(string)
```

but problem with this code is that it starts with all 62 char like this:
`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`
`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab`
`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac`
`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad`

and so on

i don't know why to be honest if someone can explain to me what is happening

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the usage of the optional argument `repeat`. When you put `repeat=62`, it equals to you put 62 `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'` to the `itertools.product`. That's why the output will always be strings of 62 characters.

The following code should work and easy to understand

```py
from itertools import permutations

def all_perms(iters):
    for n in range(1, len(iters) + 1):
        for perm in permutations(iters, n):
            yield perm

for res in all_perms('abc'):
    print(''.join(res))
```

Or shorter by using `yield from` in Python3

```py
from itertools import permutations

def all_perms(iters):
    for n in range(1, len(iters) + 1):
        yield from permutations(iters, n)
```

Comment: It's not realistic to print out all the possible strings from `'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'`...you can do some math to see how many permutations for this string.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a modified version of the `powerset` recipe using `itertools.permutations`. Also, I'm not sure why you are using `imap` if this is tagged Python 3.x. I'll just use `map` and `range`; change it to `imap` and `xrange` if needed:

```
from itertools import chain, permutations

def all_perms(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(permutations(s, r) for r in range(len(s) + 1))

for s in map(''.join, all_perms('abc')):
    print(s)
```

The order is slightly different, as it is sorted by length:

```
a
b
c
ab
ac
ba
bc
ca
cb
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import itertools

ls = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890")
result = []
n = 3
for i in range(1,n+1):
    result.extend(list(itertools.permutations(ls[:i])))
```

just define n to be your limit